# Java Swing stack components vertically without spreading out

Tags: java, swing, layout, alignment, jpanel

I've been trying for ages to get a list of JPanels to stack vertically  without spreading out to all available vertical space.

The container is a JPanel with a BoxLayout

Here is what is happening and what I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmJgj.png

I've tried using Box.Filler, Box.createGlue(), adjusting alignment properties (they seem to be pretty much useless). Each item calls setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);

Still doesn't work.

Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `BoxLayout` at the `PAGE_START` of a `BorderLayout`.